# How to read this grammar? (The C Programming Language 2e)

Tags: c, grammar

This grammar is from the reference section of 'The C Programming Language 2e'.

**A.7.6 Multiplicative operators**

> The multiplicative operators *, /, and % group left-to-right.
>
> ```
> multiplicative-expression:
>    multiplicative-expression * cast-expression
>    multiplicative-expression / cast-expression
>    multiplicative-expression % cast-expression
> ```

I understand that multiplicative-expression consists of three sub expressions. but it looks like a circular grammar for me. Because the grammar does not include terminal expressions like 'primary expression'.

How to read this grammar?

Comment: You sure there isn't another line? Maybe on the next page? There should be a line saying something like just `cast-expression`. If not, it's an error.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive reference should be one of the standards or a draft standard which both the C99 and C11 are publicly available. If we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.5` *Multiplicative operators* the grammar is as follows:

```
multiplicative-expression:
    cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression * cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression / cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression % cast-expression
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is indeed amiss with the production as presented!

There should be a rule `multiplicative-expression: cast-expression` somewhere; see [The syntax of C in Backus-Naur Form](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm).

*However*, the same grammar as presented in the post (without the rule above) appears in the PDFs ('88/2e print) I've found online and there is no [errata](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) note on the topic - maybe there should be ;-)